# While trying to convert a string to Int I face an issue which says missing parametertype for expanded function. Why and how do I resolve it?

Tags: scala

I am trying to do this,

```
val ck : String => Integer = {_ match {case _=> _.toInt}}
```

but it throws an error

missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.toInt)

why does this happen? and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Changing your function to `val ck : String => Integer = _ match {case x : String => x.toInt}` should work. Update your question for your specific needs so that you get all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 'how to fix it' is pretty simple:

```
val k: String => Int = _.toInt
```

Answer to 'why' is longer. I'll try to describe verbally what your code does, hope that helps.

```
_ match { // Match function parameter to
    _ /* Any value */ => _.toInt // And return a lambda function 
                                 //which accepts a param and calls toInt on it
}
```

So type of your expression is `A => (B => C)` - you have a function which accepts some value of type `A` and return a function from some other type `B` to type `C`. Now when Scala compiler tries to infer types given the result should be `String => Int` it fails and gives this message.